# why is autowired null? use spring jersey integration

Tags: spring, jersey, webservice-client, autowired

I have a application controller with a method getApplication(). This method returns a applicationJson objekt for my client.
In this method i call on an application builder.

The application builder is a factory and generate a special application builder object.
In the special application builders be used mapper and services, the services used daos.

All services and daos sind beans and confirgure in the applicationContext.xml and serviceBeans.xml.

When calling the method getApplication() is an exception in my eclipse java console.

The problem occurs in the class MobileApplicationBuilder and method buildPagenaviData()

Class ApplicationController:

```
package core.application.controller;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import core.application.builder.ApplicationBuilder;
import core.application.builder.MobileApplicationBuilder;
import core.application.factories.ApplicationControllerProcessHelperFactory;
import core.application.mapper.json.ApplicationJson;
import core.application.process.helper.MobileApplicationBuildHelper;
import core.base.abstracts.ControllerAbstract;
import core.security.model.interfaces.SystemSettingsModelInterface;
import core.security.service.interfaces.SystemLanguagesServiceInterface;
import core.security.service.interfaces.SystemSettingsServiceInterface;
import core.security.service.interfaces.SystemUserServiceInterface;

/**
 * 
 * Class: {@link ApplicationController}
 * 
 * Über diesen Controller wird die Anwendung zusammengebaut und als großes JSON Objekt an den Client geschickt.
 *
 */
@Path("/app")
@Component
@Scope("session")
public class ApplicationController extends ControllerAbstract  {
    private static final String JSON_PATH = System.getProperty("wtp.deploy") + "/decon_fm_version5/WEB-INF/classes/json/";

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationBuilder applicationBuilder;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("systemUserService")
    private SystemUserServiceInterface systemUserService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("systemLanguagesService")
    private SystemLanguagesServiceInterface languagesService;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("systemSettingsService")
    private SystemSettingsServiceInterface systemSettings;

    private ApplicationJson applicationJson = null;

    private String test;

    public String getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(String test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

    /**
     * Process für den Build der gesamten Applikation.
     * Es wird ein gemapptes JSON Objekt zurück gegeben welches dann auf dem Client verarbeitet werden kann.
     * Größere Build Logiken werden in eine Helper Klasse ausgelagert, welche über eine entsprechende Factory geladen wird.
     * @return
     */
    @GET
    @Path("/build")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON + ";charset=utf-8")
    public ApplicationJson getApplication() {
        // auslesen und Zuwiesung der User Settings
        SystemSettingsModelInterface settingsModel = systemSettings.getSettingsByUser(Long.parseLong(session.getAttribute("idUser").toString()));
        systemUserService.model().setSettings(settingsModel);

        applicationBuilder.setClientApp(settingsModel.getClientView())
            .setSession(session)
            .setUserModel(this.deconSecurity.getUser());
        applicationJson = applicationBuilder.build();

        return applicationJson;
    }
}
```

Class ApplicationBuilder:

```
package core.application.builder;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

import org.apache.commons.lang.WordUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;

import core.application.mapper.json.ApplicationJson;
import core.security.model.interfaces.SystemUserModelInterface;
import core.security.service.interfaces.SystemLanguagesServiceInterface;

public class ApplicationBuilder {
    /**
     * Klassennamen Suffix für jeden Builder
     */
    private static final String CLASS_SUFFIX = "ApplicationBuilder";

    /**
     * http session objekt aus dem controller
     */
    private HttpSession session;

    /**
     * Client Application die vom Nutzer eingestellt wurde
     */
    private String clientApp;

    private SystemUserModelInterface userModel;

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("systemLanguagesService")
    private SystemLanguagesServiceInterface languageService;

    /**
     * Auszuführender Builder gegen Interface Sicherung
     */
    private ApplicationBuilderInterface builder;

    public ApplicationJson build() {
        ApplicationJson application = null;

        try {
            builder = (ApplicationBuilderInterface) Class.forName("core.application.builder." + WordUtils.capitalize(clientApp) + CLASS_SUFFIX).newInstance();
            builder.setSession(session);
            builder.setUserModel(userModel);
            builder.setLanguages(languageService.getLanguages());
            builder.setFavorite(userModel.getSettings().getFavorite());
            application = builder.build();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return application;
    }

    public ApplicationBuilder setClientApp(String clientApp) {
        this.clientApp = clientApp;
        return this;
    }

    public ApplicationBuilder setSession(HttpSession session) {
        this.session = session;
        return this;
    }

    public ApplicationBuilder setUserModel(SystemUserModelInterface userModel) {
        this.userModel = userModel;
        return this;
    }
}
```

Class MobileApplicationBuilder:

```
package core.application.builder;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException;
import org.codehaus.jackson.map.JsonMappingException;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import core.application.mapper.json.ApplicationAnimateDataJson;
import core.application.mapper.json.ApplicationIconbarJson;
import core.application.mapper.json.ApplicationJson;
import core.application.mapper.json.ApplicationPagenaviJson;
import core.application.mapper.json.Formular;
import core.application.mapper.json.MobileApplicationJson;
import core.cache.model.interfaces.ApplicationCacheModelInterface;
import core.cache.service.ApplicationCacheService;

@Component
@Scope("session")
public class MobileApplicationBuilder extends ApplicationBuilderAbstract implements ApplicationBuilderInterface {
    private static final String JSON_PATH = System.getProperty("wtp.deploy") + "/decon_fm_version5/WEB-INF/classes/json/";

    private MobileApplicationJson mapper = new MobileApplicationJson();

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("applicationCacheService")
    private ApplicationCacheService applicationCacheService;

    public ApplicationJson build() {
        mapper.setStartPage(getFavorite())
            .setSystemLangguages(getLanguages())
            .setSystemUser(getUserModel());
        buildIconbar();
        buildAnimateData();
        buildPagenaviData();
        return mapper;
    }

    /**
     * Zusammenbau sämtlicher Iconbars im System
     */
    protected void buildIconbar() {
        ApplicationIconbarJson iconbarMapper = new ApplicationIconbarJson();

        File directory = new File(JSON_PATH + "/iconbars/");
        File[] files = directory.listFiles();
        Formular formsMapper = new Formular();

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {

            try {
                byte[] iconbar = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(files[i].getAbsolutePath()));
                iconbarMapper = getObjectMapper().readValue(iconbar, ApplicationIconbarJson.class);
                mapper.setIconbars(iconbarMapper.getName().toString(), iconbarMapper);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    /**
     * Zusammenbau der Animate Pages für die Application
     */
    protected void buildAnimateData() {
        ApplicationAnimateDataJson aadnMapper = new ApplicationAnimateDataJson();

        try {
            byte[] animateData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(JSON_PATH + "anmiate_data.json"));
            aadnMapper = getObjectMapper().readValue(animateData, ApplicationAnimateDataJson.class);
            mapper.setAnimateData(aadnMapper);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    /**
     * Zusammenbau des Objektes für Daten der Module welche in der Applikation verfügbar sein sollen
     */
    protected void buildPagenaviData() {
        String component = "pagenaviData";
//      ApplicationCacheServiceInterface cacheService = new ApplicationCacheService();
        // here arises a problem
        ApplicationCacheModelInterface cache = applicationCacheService.getCacheResource(
                Long.parseLong(session.getAttribute("idUser").toString()), 
                component, 
                deconSecurity().getUser().getSettings().getClientView());

        if (cache == null) {
            List<ApplicationPagenaviJson> list = null;
            File directory = new File(JSON_PATH + "/pagesnavi/");
            File[] files = directory.listFiles();

            for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                try {
                    String key = files[i].getName().substring(0, files[i].getName().indexOf("."));
                    byte[] navi = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get(files[i].getAbsolutePath()));
                    list = getObjectMapper().readValue(navi, getObjectMapper().getTypeFactory().constructCollectionType(
                            List.class, ApplicationPagenaviJson.class));
                    mapper.setPagenaviData(key, list);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            // cache Module Event um die Daten für die Pagenavi nach Rechten zu kontrollieren und entsprechend in den Cache zu speichern
            eventDispatcher().dispatch("cleanAndCachePagenaviData", this);
        } else {
            try {
                HashMap<String, List<ApplicationPagenaviJson>> map = getObjectMapper().readValue(
                    cache.getJsonObject(),
                    HashMap.class);
                mapper.setPagenaviData(map);
            } catch (JsonParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JsonMappingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Class ApplicationCacheService:

```
package core.cache.service;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import core.cache.dao.interfaces.ApplicationCacheDaoInterface;
import core.cache.model.interfaces.ApplicationCacheModelInterface;
import core.cache.service.interfaces.ApplicationCacheServiceInterface;

/**
 * Class: ApplicationCacheService
 * 
 * Service Klasse für das verwalten einer Application Cache Speicherung
 *
 */
@Service
public class ApplicationCacheService implements ApplicationCacheServiceInterface {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("applicationCacheDao")
    private ApplicationCacheDaoInterface cacheDao;

    public void saveCacheObject(Object obj) {
        cacheDao.saveCacheObject(obj);
    }

    public boolean isCacheUpdated(Long id, String applicationComponent) {
        return cacheDao.isCacheUpdated(id, applicationComponent);
    }

    public ApplicationCacheModelInterface getCacheResource(Long idUser, String applicationComponent, String applicationType) {
        return cacheDao.getCacheResource(idUser, applicationComponent, applicationType);
    }
}
```

Class ApplicationCacheDao:

```
package core.cache.dao;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import core.base.abstracts.DeconDaoAbstract;
import core.cache.dao.interfaces.ApplicationCacheDaoInterface;
import core.cache.model.ApplicationCacheModel;
import core.cache.model.interfaces.ApplicationCacheModelInterface;

/**
 * Class: ApplicationCacheDao
 * 
 * DAO Klasse für das speichern, auslesen und verwalten der ApplicationCache Tabelle
 *
 */
@Repository
@Transactional
public class ApplicationCacheDao extends DeconDaoAbstract implements ApplicationCacheDaoInterface {

    public void saveCacheObject(Object obj) {
        try {
            super.getSession().save(obj);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public boolean isCacheUpdated(Long id, String applicationComponent) {
        boolean isUpdated = false;
        String hql = "from ApplicationCacheModel where idUser = " + id + " AND applicationComponent = '" + applicationComponent + "'";
        List<ApplicationCacheModel> list = super.getSession().createQuery(hql).list();

        if (list.size() == 0) {
            isUpdated = true;
        } else {
            ApplicationCacheModel obj = list.get(0);

            if (obj.isUpdate() != false) {
                isUpdated = true;
            }
        }

        return isUpdated;
    }

    public ApplicationCacheModelInterface getCacheResource(Long idUser, String applicationComponent, String applicationType) {
        String hql = "from ApplicationCacheModel where idUser = " + idUser + " AND applicationComponent = '" + applicationComponent + "' AND applicationType = '" + applicationType +"'";
        List<ApplicationCacheModel> list = super.getSession().createQuery(hql).list();

        return (list.size() > 0) ? list.get(0) : null;
    }
}
```

serviceBeans.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.1.xsd">

    <!-- User Service -->
    <bean id="systemUserService" class="core.security.service.SystemUserService"></bean>
    <bean id="systemUserModel" class="core.security.model.SystemUserModel" />
    <bean id="systemUserDao" class="core.security.dao.SystemUserDao" />

    <!-- SystemRolesService -->
    <bean id="systemRoleService" class="core.security.service.SystemRoleService"></bean>
    <bean id="systemRoleModel" class="core.security.model.SystemRoleModel"></bean>
    <bean id="systemRoleDao" class="core.security.dao.SystemRoleDao"></bean>

    <!-- SystemGroupService -->
    <bean id="systemGroupService" class="core.security.service.SystemGroupService"></bean>
    <bean id="systemGroupModel" class="core.security.model.SystemGroupModel"></bean>
    <bean id="systemGroupDao" class="core.security.dao.SystemGroupDao"></bean>

    <!-- SystemLanguagesService -->
    <bean id="systemLanguagesService" class="core.security.service.SystemLanguagesService"></bean>
    <bean id="systemLanguagesModel" class="core.security.model.SystemLanguagesModel"></bean>
    <bean id="systemLanguagesDao" class="core.security.dao.SystemLanguagesDao"></bean>

    <!-- System Setting Service -->
    <bean id="systemSettingsService" class="core.security.service.SystemSettingsService"></bean>
    <bean id="systemSettingsModel" class="core.security.model.SystemSettingsModel"></bean>
    <bean id="systemSettingsDao" class="core.security.dao.SystemSettingsDao"></bean>

    <!-- ApplicationCacheService -->
    <bean id="applicationCacheModel" class="core.cache.model.ApplicationCacheModel"></bean>
    <bean id="applicationCacheDao" class="core.cache.dao.ApplicationCacheDao"></bean>
    <bean id="applicationCacheService" class="core.cache.service.ApplicationCacheService"></bean>
</beans>
```

applicationContext.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:oxm="http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm"
    xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/oxm/spring-oxm-3.1.xsd">

        <context:annotation-config />

        <context:component-scan base-package="core.application.controller" />
        <context:component-scan base-package="core.security.controller" />
        <context:component-scan base-package="core.cache.controller" />

        <import resource="database/hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
        <import resource="serviceBeans.xml"/>

        <bean id="objectMapper" class="org.codehaus.jackson.map.ObjectMapper"></bean>
        <bean id="jsonFactory" class="org.codehaus.jackson.JsonFactory"></bean>

        <bean id="mobileJsonMapper" class="core.application.mapper.json.MobileApplicationJson"></bean>
        <bean id="desktopJsonMapper" class="core.application.mapper.json.DesktopApplicationJson"></bean>

        <bean id="mobileApplicationBuilder" class="core.application.builder.MobileApplicationBuilder">
        </bean>
        <bean id="desktopApplicationBuilder" class="core.application.builder.DesktopApplicationBuilder"></bean>
        <bean id="applicationBuilder" class="core.application.builder.ApplicationBuilder"></bean>

        <bean id="deconModuleConfigParser" class="core.base.beans.DeconModuleConfigParser"></bean>
        <bean id="deconSessionManager" class="core.base.beans.DeconSessionManager" scope="session"></bean>

        <bean id="eventConfigLoader" class="core.event.dispatcher.EventConfigLoader">
            <constructor-arg ref="deconModuleConfigParser" />
        </bean>
        <bean id="eventFactory" class="core.event.dispatcher.EventFactory"></bean>
        <bean id="eventDispatcher" class="core.event.dispatcher.EventDispatcher">
            <constructor-arg ref="eventFactory" />
            <constructor-arg ref="eventConfigLoader" />
        </bean>

        <bean id="deconSecurity" class="core.base.beans.DeconSecurity"></bean>

<!--        <bean id="sce" class="javax.servlet.ServletContextEvent"></bean> -->

<!--        <import resource="jsonMapperBeans.xml"/> -->
</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Decon FM Version 5</display-name>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>classpath:META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>core.base.listeners.DeconSession</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Rest Service</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.spring.container.servlet.SpringServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>
                core.application.controller;
                core.security.controller;
                core.cache.controller; 
                org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Rest Service</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

The Exception message:

```
SEVERE: The RuntimeException could not be mapped to a response, re-throwing to the HTTP container
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at core.application.builder.MobileApplicationBuilder.buildPagenaviData(MobileApplicationBuilder.java:94)
    at core.application.builder.MobileApplicationBuilder.build(MobileApplicationBuilder.java:47)
    at core.application.builder.ApplicationBuilder.build(ApplicationBuilder.java:49)
    at core.application.controller.ApplicationController.getApplication(ApplicationController.java:81)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:302)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1480)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1411)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1360)
    at com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1350)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:538)
    at com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:716)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You have provided a lot of code here, please consider revising your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

I had an overview of your code, I figured the issue. Let me explain why null pointer first.
In your code there are two containers created; Spring and Jersey.
When Jersey is executed you are trying to fetch a bean from spring container, this is not possible , so you need a super container like the (Application Context) to retrieve that bean which is in spring container.

The solution is simple in spring.
Solution : Instead of autowired as dependency injection use this WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext.getBean(“beanName”);

This is just one way, there are many other ways for dependency injection through Application Context. Try to understand the problem it will help you to get to core of spring bean creation. Rest this solution should work. Cheers